# How are the coefficients of sklearn.linear_model LinearRegression module returned

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am performing a simple autoregressive model using sklearn.linear_model and the module LinearRegression. You can see my code below. The training dataset is in `train` and `X` contains the lagged version of the target. The least lagged data, i.e. the data lagged with a lag of 1, is in the first column of X and the last column contains the most lagged data.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.linear_model as skml 
tot_param = 10
X = np.zeros((len(train),tot_param))
for i in range(1,tot_param):
    aux = np.roll(train,-i)
    aux[-i:] = 0
    X[:,-i] = aux

lregr = skml.LinearRegression()
model = lregr.fit(X,train)
```

I would therefore expect that the coefficients in `model.coef_` would be ordered based on the columns of `X`, i.e. the first element would contain the coefficient related to the least lagged data. If I execute the code with `tot_params=1`, I only get one coefficient with value `0.97190325`. However, if I choose `tot_params=2`, I get `model.coef_=[-0.00433893,  0.97612027]`; clearly, the second value (`0.97612027`) refers to the least lagged data. But why is that? I would expect an output like `model.coef_=[0.97612027, -0.00433893]`, with the coefficient of the least lagged data in front.

The same thing happens for other values of `tot_params`. For instance, for `tot_params=6`, I get `[ 3.71898345e-02,  5.46416689e-02, -8.65343583e-02, -1.88565771e-03, -6.13451823e-04,  9.72547863e-01]`, which once again clearly indicates that the least lagged data is put at the end and not at the beginning of the returned list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there: `X[:,-i] = aux`

The larger i -> the larger the lag -> the larger the distance from the last column:
i=1 is column -1
i=6 is column -6, so that would be the first one.

Change it to `X[:, i-1] = aux` if you prefer it the other way around.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake...thank you Jondiedoop for spotting it